# Add Poppler to Path in Debian

Tags: path, debian, poppler

I have just installed poppler on my debian server using the command:

sudo apt-get install poppler-utils

However, when I execute the command:

pdftocairo --help

The function cannot be found, so I assume this program has not automatically linked into my PATH variable. My issue is that I am not very experienced with Linux and I don't know how to find out where poppler installed, nor how to create a link file to Poppler from an existing included PATH location.

Any help would be appreciated, especially if someone can explain how I know where these programs are installing themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not need to do anything with the `PATH` - it's the maintainer's task to make everything work "as expected".

Your problem could have several reasons:

- your version of `poppler-utils` does not come with the `pdftocairo` binary
- your version of `poppler-utils` installs `pdftocairo` into a path that is not in your `PATH`
- you (or somebody else) have messed with the `PATH`, so it doesn't contain the directory where `poppler-utils` installed the binaries to any more.

So first check whether `poppler-utils` installs the file (and where to).
The following will give you a list of all files installed by the package:

```
$ dpkg -L poppler-utils
[...]
/usr/bin/pdftops
/usr/bin/pdftocairo
/usr/bin/pdftohtml
[...]
```

As you can see, on my system - which has `poppler-utils 0.18.4-6` installed - the package installed a `pdftocairo` into `/usr/bin` which is the *default* path for all applications, and which should already be in your PATH.

To check your PATH variable do something like

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games
```

As you can see, my `PATH` contains `/usr/bin`, and indeed i can do:

```
$ pdftocairo --help
pdftocairo version 0.18.4
Copyright 2005-2011 The Poppler Developers - http://poppler.freedesktop.org
Copyright 1996-2004 Glyph & Cog, LLC
[...]
```

If your `PATH` does not contain `/usr/bin`, then something is seriously wrong with your system (for instance, you have tried changing your path and accidentally removed all the previous settings).

In any case, adding a new path to PATH is quite simple; all paths are separated by colons, so you should do something like the following:

```
$ export PATH=/path/to/my/bin:${PATH}
```

This will add `/path/to/my/bin/` at the beginning of the search-path, so all binaries will now be searched first in `/path/to/my/bin/` and then `/usr/local/bin` and so forth.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It turns out my version of Debian (Squeeze) was only using poppler 12.X which didn't contain pdftocairo. Thanks for pointing this out - the dpkg -L poppler-utils command showed that the program didn't exist.