# How to fix 'Is poppler installed and in PATH?' in R

Tags: python, r, poppler, reticulate

I'm running a python script in R using reticulate. I use py_discover_config() for finding Python config. I am using anaconda. I don't really understand environments and why I would need one.

I tried use_python() and use_condaenv() even installing packages with conda_install.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)
library(reticulate)

py_discover_config()
# Set the path to the Python executable file
source_python("~/projects/stiekemthuis/API.py")

json_list <- api_fun() %>% toJSON()
```

It had no problem importing the python libraries:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
import io, json
import os
from PIL import Image
import requests
import sys
```

I got an error at line 25:

```
pages = convert_from_path(files[0], 300)
```

Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?

I tried to setwd() to a the path of the binaries of poppler. 
What can be done?

Comment: Does this answer the question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332238/add-poppler-to-path-in-debian/17340158#17340158 . I would not expect changing the working directory to help.

Answer (score 0):

I stopped using the library(reticulate) and started using system2 for direct execution through python command followed by the path to script:

```
command = "python"
allArgs = c(path2script)

output = system2(command, args=allArgs, stdout=TRUE)

json_list <-output %>% fromJSON()
```

I used code from another thread in my python script:

```
print(json.dumps(res, sort_keys=False, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))
```

Because my formatting of the Json string was bad.